# What is the dot limit notation?

Tags: number-theory

In this book I am reading, we consider some element $x = (x_n) \in Z_p$ and if $y_n \in Z$ such that $y_n \equiv x_n \pmod{p^n}$ then $\lim \textbf{.} y_n = x.$ What is the does limit mean in this context and what is the dot?

Comment: Are you reading Serre's Course in Arithmetic, and is $Z_p$ supposed to be the $p$-adic integers $\mathbf Z_p$?

Comment: yes! everything you said is right.

Comment: The dot is peculiar notation that means the same thing as $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} y_n = x$.